# AJAX POST success and error firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I checked many posts here regarding same issue but nothing was working, and more or less it behaves like a glitch:

```
function onbtnclick(){


    var user_email=$('#user_email').val();
    var send_data = {email:user_email};

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'someURL.php',
        crossDomain: true,
        data:send_data,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert("Thank you for the mailing list");
        },
        error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Your email is already in our mailing list.');
            console.log('log e:'+responseData);
            console.log('log e:'+textStatus);
            console.log('log e:'+errorThrown);
        }
    });

        return false;

 }
};


<form name="myform">
    <input  id="user_email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email Here" style="width:300px" required><br>
    <br><button type="submit" class="leka-button button-style2 offer_button" onclick="onbtnclick()"><h5>SIGN UP</h5></button>
</form>
```

Simply i'm trying to alert the proper message if the user new to fire success or if he registered to fire error, I tried to remove dataType:'text'  or adding 'json' and\with removing crossDomain attribute as well but all didn't give me the reason.
In case this was useful, [here is where I fire the AJAX script.](http://www.ayaami.com/site/special-offer)

Comment: common mistake: returning error 200 with no content, leads to an error. return the code 204 (OK, no content) in the API.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant in fact, in the success event i'm alert-ing the resposneData, textStatus, errorThrown but it seems it's not even going inside the success.

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Does the success function fire? Does the error function fire? What is the response? What errors are thrown?

Comment: @Quentin it register the email into the database, and none of success or error functions fire. the only error i have is: 
Uncaught TypeError: c.getAttribute is not a function
And not sure if it's related or not.

Answer (score 0):

You call the JavaScript when you click on a submit button.

The JavaScript runs. The Ajax request is prepared. The JavaScript finishes. The submit button's default behaviour submits the form. The page unloads. The Ajax request is *canceled*. The regular form submission takes place.

Get rid of the `onclick` attribute. Bind your event handlers with JavaScript instead.

```
$(function () {
    var $form = $([name="myform"]); // `name` is obsolete for form elements, give it an ID instead
    $form.on('submit', onbtnclick);

    function onbtnclick(event) { // Give this function a better name
        event.preventDefault(); // Don't submit the form normally
        // Then put the rest of your existing code
    }
});
```

Comment: Makes for me some logic, will try and let you know.

Comment: Sorry to ask, first the <form></form> is fine or shall i take the <button> outside? I followed for the moment the same snippet you shared above without applying the changes in comment but I don't see it give me changes.

Comment: @SadiqJaffer - Did you get rid of the onclick attribute? That's really important.

Comment: Yes I got rid off the onclick attribute from the button.

Comment: Or simply you can make the `<button type="button"` - that will do similar thing.